# When is it beneficial to train Tesseract?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract in my project to convert images that I've scanned from french newspapers.
I want to know if I need to train Tesseract in order to recognize the french fonts and the specification of this language such as "caret", "circumflex accent" , etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the standard issue `fra` data language does not produce acceptable results, then you may consider [training](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract). Tesseract recognizes diacritical characters very well.